# Can you use Catleap display with MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I've read several people doing this, but the ebay description page warns against using with a Mac.

For ex. -> http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-YAMAKASI-CATLEAP-Q270-SE-27-LED-2560X1440-WQHD-DVI-D-Dual-Computer-Monitor-/140738200221?pt=Computer_Monitors&hash=item20c4a6829d

It is contradictory and confusing to say the least. Have others used Catleap with success? ( any warnings ) ?

Comment: I'm not seeing in the description where it recommends against using the display with a Mac. However, the question is why *wouldn't* it work with a Mac. A monitor is a monitor. As long as it can connect, it should work. Why would you think it wouldn't, (except for the warning)?

Comment: the warning is midway through the desc. in a blue box.  i guess they're saying that to protect themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, days of reading later; the answer is 'Yes' with following requirements

- Need to output a native dual link DVI signal at 2560x1440
- Need a mini Display port to Dual Link DVI ( Apple or Monoprice)